# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

> I'm trying to add an **[action buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-action-button)** to my **[shedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars)** app

***source code***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import {Agenda} from 'react-native-calendars';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {}
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Agenda
        items={this.state.items}
        loadItemsForMonth={this.loadItems.bind(this)}
        selected={'2017-05-16'}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        renderEmptyDate={this.renderEmptyDate.bind(this)}
        rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged.bind(this)}

      />
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}}>
        {/* Rest of the app comes ABOVE the action button component !*/}
        <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="Create Shedule" onPress={() => console.log("Create Shedule!")}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#3498db' title="Notifications" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="md-notifications-off" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="All Tasks" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
        </ActionButton>
      </View>
    );
  this.confirmDate = this.confirmDate.bind(this);
  this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
  }

  loadItems(day) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const strTime = this.timeToString(time);
        if (!this.state.items[strTime]) {
          this.state.items[strTime] = [];
          const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
          for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            this.state.items[strTime].push({
              name: 'Item for ' + strTime,
              height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
            });
          }
        }
      }
      //console.log(this.state.items);
      const newItems = {};
      Object.keys(this.state.items).forEach(key => {newItems[key] = this.state.items[key];});
      this.setState({
        items: newItems
      });
    }, 1000);
    // console.log(`Load Items for ${day.year}-${day.month}`);
  }

  renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.item, {height: item.height}]}><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
    );
  }

  renderEmptyDate() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyDate}><Text>This is empty date!</Text></View>
    );
  }

  rowHasChanged(r1, r2) {
    return r1.name !== r2.name;
  }

  timeToString(time) {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 17
  },
  emptyDate: {
    height: 15,
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: 30
  }
}

actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },);
```

> **This is my action button source code** (*it's also included in the above
>   code*)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';





export default function App() {
  return (
   <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}}>
        {/* Rest of the app comes ABOVE the action button component !*/}
        <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="Create Shedule" onPress={() => console.log("Create Shedule!")}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#3498db' title="Notifications" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="md-notifications-off" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="All Tasks" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
        </ActionButton>
      </View>
    );
  }



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

> **This is the error i'm getting**
>   [image: error i'm getting]
>
> **This is how it should look like**
>   [image: view]

from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars#agenda) you can get the calendar & this is the [action button](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select) 
I tried to add the action buttons but I keep getting the above error
Can you help me to fix this issue

#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wrap Agenda and View components in a fragment tag.

```
<>
    <Agenda />
    <View />
</>
```

It should work

The empty tag is a shortcut for `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: The issue is very common. The return statement returns 2 components but it should return only one. That's the reason why you have to wrap both components in a parent component. If you wrapped it correctly you shouldn't get the same error. Can you double check your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to reacts jsx architecture, everything must be wrapped inside a parent jsx element. So in your case
 and  doesn't have a parent tag, so either wrap it around a  or a <>.  Like the below

<>

Or

Hope it helps. Feel free for doubts.